# How do I recruit the old CPUs to my party?

Tags: hyperdimension-neptunia-mk2

I just beat the game and noitced there's trophies for Vert, Noire and Blanc joining the party. I didn't get them (but I did get Neptune) while playing the story normally.

How can I get the other CPUs to join my party?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recruit any of the three you have to reach **Chapter 5** (when Neptune joins your party). You then need to increase the shares in a certain city to at least **50%** to trigger a cutscene and they will join you.

- For **Vert**, you have to increase the shares in the city of **Leanbox**.
- For **Noire**, you have to increase the shares in the city of **Lastation**.
- For **Blanc**, you have to increase the shares in the city of **Lowee**.

Comment: There's no time limit then? Anytime in chapter 5 I can do this and get them?

Comment: I believe that as long as you have Neptune in your party, you can trigger the events. You don't have to fight them in this game.